# Replace urllib.request urlopen in PHP

Tags: php, video, download

I have a URL which can not download using video file using PHP. I have to run it ones in browser so that code can start downloading videos from it.

I have tried using curl, it fails to download video on first hit to url through code.
I have tried using Ajax call by creating video blob, it works however because of cron job, javascript can not work.

I need solution in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Guzzle in PHP

```
   require_once('guzzle/vendor/autoload.php');

   use GuzzleHttp\Client;
   use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

   $client = new Client();
   $url = 'video url'; // URL of the file to download
   $file_name = 'filename.mp4';
   $saveTo = $save_file_loc = __DIR__."/".$file_name; // Local path to save the file

   try {
       $response = $client->request('GET', $url, ['sink' => $saveTo]);
       echo "File downloaded successfully to " . $saveTo;
   } catch (RequestException $e) {
       echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
       if ($e->hasResponse()) {
           echo "\nHTTP Status Code: " . $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
       }
   }
```

Comment: This code is working correctly when run independently, however when I put it in PHP file with rest of the code, then Guzzle related codes start giving errors. Any idea how it can be fixed? I am using latest version of Guzzle with correct version of PHP 8.1 as needed by Guzzle. Current error showing: Fatal error: "Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: URI must be a string or UriInterface in vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Utils.php:461"

Comment: I suggest you to use $url like this: $response = $client->request('GET', "".$url."", ['sink' => $save_file_loc]);